# ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution File <path>.java can't be indexed twice

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, devops, sonarqube-scan

I've Sonar version 6.0 and there following command scans perfectly -

`/home/oracle/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/Sonar6/bin/sonar-scanner -e -Dsonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx2G -Dsonar.host.url=http://ip-address:9000/ -Dsonar.projectKey=BI7_9 -Dsonar.projectName=BI7_9 -Dsonar.analysis.mode=publish -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true -Dsonar.issuesReport.console.enable=true -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev`

Now I've another Sonar server with version 7.6 and if same above is executed by changing ip of new sonar server, it fails with following -

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
File <path>.java can't be indexed twice. Please check that inclusion/exclusion patterns 
produce disjoint sets for main and test files
```

Please guide me what settings I need to do on latest sonar server in order it to work.

**EDIT**

Following is my `sonar-project.properties` file -

```
sonar.projectKey=eBO79
sonar.projectName= e-BO 7.9
sonar.projectVersion=7.9_Dev
sonar.scm.disabled=true
sonar.java.source=1.8
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.modules=Source,UI
sonar.sources=.
```

After running in debug mode, following is the log -

```
14:29:35.938 INFO: Option -e/--errors is no longer supported and will be ignored
14:29:35.945 INFO: Scanner configuration file: /home/oracle/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/Sonar/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
14:29:35.946 INFO: Project root configuration file: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/sonar-project.properties
14:29:36.035 INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.2.0.1227
14:29:36.035 INFO: Java 1.8.0_242 Oracle Corporation (64-bot)
14:29:36.035 INFO: bonux 3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64 amd64
14:29:36.147 DEBUG: keyStore is : 
14:29:36.147 DEBUG: keyStore type is : jks
14:29:36.147 DEBUG: keyStore provider is : 
14:29:36.147 DEBUG: init keystore
14:29:36.148 DEBUG: init keymanager of type SunX509
14:29:36.204 DEBUG: Create: /home/oracle/.sonar/cache
14:29:36.205 INFO: User cache: /home/oracle/.sonar/cache
14:29:36.205 DEBUG: Create: /home/oracle/.sonar/cache/_tmp
14:29:36.208 DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
14:29:36.216 DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
14:29:36.216 DEBUG: Download: http://localhost:9000/batch/index
14:29:36.253 DEBUG: Get bootstrap completed
14:29:36.260 DEBUG: Create isolated classloader...
14:29:36.269 DEBUG: Start temp cleaning...
14:29:36.275 DEBUG: Temp cleaning done
14:29:36.275 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
14:29:36.278 INFO: SonarQube server 7.6.0
14:29:36.279 INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
14:29:36.280 DEBUG: Work directory: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork
14:29:36.281 DEBUG: Execution execute
14:29:36.530 INFO: Load global settings
14:29:36.569 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/settings/values.protobuf | time=31ms
14:29:36.589 INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=61ms
14:29:36.591 INFO: Server id: C1CEBDFC-AW6xf5R4c7Kz5gBax126
14:29:36.606 INFO: User cache: /home/oracle/.sonar/cache
14:29:36.794 INFO: Load/download plugins
14:29:36.794 INFO: Load plugins index
14:29:36.802 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/plugins/installed | time=8ms
14:29:36.831 INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=37ms
14:29:36.863 INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=69ms
14:29:36.915 DEBUG: Plugins:
14:29:36.916 DEBUG:   * SonarPython 1.11.0.2473 (python)
14:29:36.916 DEBUG:   * SonarCSS 1.0.3.724 (cssfamily)
14:29:36.916 DEBUG:   * JaCoCo 1.0.1.143 (jacoco)
14:29:36.916 DEBUG:   * SonarGo 1.1.0.1612 (go)
14:29:36.916 DEBUG:   * SonarKotbon 1.4.0.155 (kotbon)
14:29:36.916 DEBUG:   * Svn 1.9.0.1295 (scmsvn)
14:29:36.916 DEBUG:   * SonarJS 5.0.0.6962 (javascript)
14:29:36.916 DEBUG:   * SonarRuby 1.4.0.155 (ruby)
14:29:36.916 DEBUG:   * SonarScala 1.4.0.155 (sonarscala)
14:29:36.916 DEBUG:   * SonarC# 7.10.0.7896 (csharp)
14:29:36.916 DEBUG:   * SonarJava 5.10.1.16922 (java)
14:29:36.916 DEBUG:   * LDAP 2.2.0.608 (ldap)
14:29:36.916 DEBUG:   * SonarHTML 3.1.0.1615 (web)
14:29:36.917 DEBUG:   * Git 1.7.0.1491 (scmgit)
14:29:36.917 DEBUG:   * SonarFlex 2.4.0.1222 (flex)
14:29:36.917 DEBUG:   * SonarXML 2.0.1.2020 (xml)
14:29:36.917 DEBUG:   * SonarPHP 2.16.0.4355 (php)
14:29:36.917 DEBUG:   * SonarTS 1.9.0.3766 (typescript)
14:29:36.917 DEBUG:   * SonarVB 7.10.0.7896 (vbnet)
14:29:36.917 DEBUG:   * HTML Report 1.1 (MyReport)
14:29:37.381 INFO: Process project properties
14:29:37.434 DEBUG: Process project properties (done) | time=53ms
14:29:37.434 INFO: Execute project builders
14:29:37.435 DEBUG: Execute project builder: org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpGlobalProtobufFileProcessor
14:29:37.441 DEBUG: Execute project builder: org.sonar.plugins.vbnet.VbNetGlobalProtobufFileProcessor
14:29:37.444 INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=10ms
14:29:37.454 INFO: Project key: bo7_9
14:29:37.455 INFO: Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev
14:29:37.455 INFO: Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork
14:29:37.455 DEBUG: Project global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.456 DEBUG: Creating module hierarchy
14:29:37.456 DEBUG:   Init module 'bo7_9'
14:29:37.457 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev
14:29:37.457 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork
14:29:37.457 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.457 DEBUG:   Init module 'Source'
14:29:37.457 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source
14:29:37.457 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source
14:29:37.457 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.457 DEBUG:   Init module 'CommonModules'
14:29:37.457 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/CommonModules
14:29:37.457 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_CommonModules
14:29:37.457 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.458 DEBUG:   Init module 'bo-appstate-impl'
14:29:37.458 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/CommonModules/bo-appstate-impl
14:29:37.458 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_CommonModules_bo-appstate-impl
14:29:37.458 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.458 DEBUG:   Init module 'bo-logging'
14:29:37.458 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/CommonModules/bo-logging
14:29:37.458 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_CommonModules_bo-logging
14:29:37.458 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.458 DEBUG:   Init module 'boservice'
14:29:37.458 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/CommonModules/boservice
14:29:37.458 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_CommonModules_boservice
14:29:37.458 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.459 DEBUG:   Init module 'boservice-api'
14:29:37.459 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/CommonModules/boservice/boservice-api
14:29:37.459 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_CommonModules_boservice_boservice-api
14:29:37.459 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.459 DEBUG:   Init module 'boservice-impl'
14:29:37.459 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/CommonModules/boservice/boservice-impl
14:29:37.459 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_CommonModules_boservice_boservice-impl
14:29:37.459 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.459 DEBUG:   Init module 'cluster'
14:29:37.460 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/CommonModules/cluster
14:29:37.460 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_CommonModules_cluster
14:29:37.460 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.460 DEBUG:   Init module 'instances'
14:29:37.460 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/CommonModules/cluster/instances
14:29:37.460 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_CommonModules_cluster_instances
14:29:37.460 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.460 DEBUG:   Init module 'notification'
14:29:37.460 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/CommonModules/cluster/notification
14:29:37.460 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_CommonModules_cluster_notification
14:29:37.460 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.460 DEBUG:   Init module 'command'
14:29:37.460 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/CommonModules/command
14:29:37.461 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_CommonModules_command
14:29:37.461 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.461 DEBUG:   Init module 'connection-helper'
14:29:37.461 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/CommonModules/connection-helper
14:29:37.461 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_CommonModules_connection-helper
14:29:37.461 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.461 DEBUG:   Init module 'connectioncache'
14:29:37.461 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/CommonModules/connectioncache
14:29:37.461 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_CommonModules_connectioncache
14:29:37.461 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.461 DEBUG:   Init module 'connectionmodule'
14:29:37.461 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/CommonModules/connectionmodule
14:29:37.462 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_CommonModules_connectionmodule
/home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_CommonModules_metadata-connection
14:29:37.464 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.464 DEBUG:   Init module 'mlvprocessor'
14:29:37.464 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/CommonModules/mlvprocessor
14:29:37.464 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_CommonModules_mlvprocessor
14:29:37.464 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.464 DEBUG:   Init module 'pluginmanager'
14:29:37.464 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/CommonModules/pluginmanager
14:29:37.464 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_CommonModules_pluginmanager
14:29:37.464 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.464 DEBUG:   Init module 'product-executor'
14:29:37.464 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/CommonModules/product-executor
14:29:37.464 DEBUG:     Working dir: 14:29:37.498 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/Utiboties/base64
14:29:37.498 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_Widgets_DataDriven_ThreeDInsightWidget
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:   Init module 'tile'
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/Widgets/DataDriven/tile
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_Widgets_DataDriven_tile
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:   Init module 'tile-widget'
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/Widgets/DataDriven/tile/tile-widget
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_Widgets_DataDriven_tile_tile-widget
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:   Init module 'tile-widget-migration'
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/Widgets/DataDriven/tile/tile-widget-migration
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_Widgets_DataDriven_tile_tile-widget-migration
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:   Init module 'NonDataDriven'
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/Widgets/NonDataDriven
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_Widgets_NonDataDriven
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:   Init module 'header-footer-widget'
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/Widgets/NonDataDriven/header-footer-widget
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_Widgets_NonDataDriven_header-footer-widget
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:   Init module 'image-widget'
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/Widgets/NonDataDriven/image-widget
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_Widgets_NonDataDriven_image-widget
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.512 DEBUG:   Init module 'bonk-widget'
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/Widgets/NonDataDriven/bonk-widget
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_Widgets_NonDataDriven_bonk-widget
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:   Init module 'portal-report-container'
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/Widgets/NonDataDriven/portal-report-container
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_Widgets_NonDataDriven_portal-report-container
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:   Init module 'standard-element'
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/Widgets/NonDataDriven/standard-element
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_Widgets_NonDataDriven_standard-element
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:   Init module 'standard-element-json-upgrader'
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/Widgets/NonDataDriven/standard-element/standard-element-json-upgrader
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_Widgets_NonDataDriven_standard-element_standard-element-json-upgrader
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:   Init module 'standard-element-widget'
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/Widgets/NonDataDriven/standard-element/standard-element-widget
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_Widgets_NonDataDriven_standard-element_standard-element-widget
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:   Init module 'traditional-report'
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/Widgets/NonDataDriven/traditional-report
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_Widgets_NonDataDriven_traditional-report
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:     Module global encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:   Init module 'traditional-report-widget-migration'
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:     Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/Widgets/NonDataDriven/traditional-report/traditional-report-widget-migration
14:29:37.513 DEBUG:     Working dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/.scannerwork/bo7_9_Source_Widgets_NonDataDriven_traditional-report_traditional-report-widget-migration
14:29:37.770 INFO: Load quaboty profiles
14:29:37.785 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/quabotyprofiles/search.protobuf?defaults=true | time=14ms
14:29:37.794 INFO: Load quaboty profiles (done) | time=24ms
14:29:37.808 INFO: Load active rules
14:29:37.819 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt&activation=true&qprofile=AW6xgse6jkN0Zrjp1X85&p=1&ps=500 | time=10ms
14:29:37.888 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt&activation=true&qprofile=AW6xgsf_jkN0Zrjp1X9v&p=1&ps=500 | time=11ms
14:29:37.898 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt&activation=true&qprofile=AW6xgshbjkN0Zrjp1X-O&p=1&ps=500 | time=6ms
14:29:37.907 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt&activation=true&qprofile=AW6xgshxjkN0Zrjp1X-v&p=1&ps=500 | time=9ms
14:29:37.936 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt&activation=true&qprofile=AW6xgsldjkN0Zrjp1YFr&p=1&ps=500 | time=14ms
14:29:37.953 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt&activation=true&qprofile=AW6xgsnTjkN0Zrjp1YHm&p=1&ps=500 | time=9ms
14:29:37.965 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt&activation=true&qprofile=AW6xgsogjkN0Zrjp1YIm&p=1&ps=500 | time=10ms
14:29:38.000 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt&activation=true&qprofile=AW6xgsqTjkN0Zrjp1YM0&p=1&ps=500 | time=32ms
14:29:38.057 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt&activation=true&qprofile=AW6xgstijkN0Zrjp1YWb&p=1&ps=500 | time=48ms
14:29:38.076 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt&activation=true&qprofile=AW6xgsyKjkN0Zrjp1Ycm&p=1&ps=500 | time=10ms
14:29:38.088 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt&activation=true&qprofile=AW6xgszyjkN0Zrjp1Ydy&p=1&ps=500 | time=11ms
14:29:38.097 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt&activation=true&qprofile=AW6xgszAjkN0Zrjp1Yc-&p=1&ps=500 | time=8ms
14:29:38.115 DEBUG: GET 200 http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt&activation=true&qprofile=AW6xgs2ojkN0Zrjp1Yhn&p=1&ps=500 | time=18ms
14:29:38.134 DEBUG: GET 200 
14:29:38.320 DEBUG: 'Source/CommonModules/boservice/boservice-impl/src/main/java/com/eqtechnologic/my/bo/api/apiimpl/bean/ExportToPdfResponse.java' indexed with language 'java'
14:29:38.321 DEBUG: 'Source/CommonModules/boservice/boservice-impl/src/main/java/com/eqtechnologic/my/bo/api/apiimpl/bean/ExportToMailSettings.java' indexed with language 'java'
14:29:38.321 DEBUG: 'Source/CommonModules/boservice/boservice-impl/src/main/java/com/eqtechnologic/my/bo/api/apiimpl/bean/HTMLExportSettings.java' indexed with language 'java'
14:29:38.321 DEBUG: 'Source/CommonModules/boservice/boservice-impl/src/main/java/com/eqtechnologic/my/bo/api/apiimpl/bean/ChangeMeasureValuesAction.java' indexed with language 'java'
14:29:38.321 DEBUG: 'Source/CommonModules/boservice/boservice-impl/src/main/java/com/eqtechnologic/my/bo/api/apiimpl/bean/PubbocConfigBean.java' indexed with language 'java'
14:29:38.322 DEBUG: 'Source/CommonModules/boservice/boservice-impl/src/main/java/com/eqtechnologic/my/bo/api/apiimpl/bean/boServiceBeansFactory.java' indexed with language 'java'
14:29:38.322 DEBUG: 'Source/CommonModules/boservice/boservice-impl/src/main/java/com/eqtechnologic/my/bo/api/apiimpl/bean/AppbocationDeploymentParameter.java' indexed with language 'java'
14:29:38.322 DEBUG: 'Source/CommonModules/boservice/boservice-impl/src/main/java/com/eqtechnologic/my/bo/api/apiimpl/bean/SnapshotFilterExpression.java' indexed with language 'java'
14:29:38.322 DEBUG: 'Source/CommonModules/boservice/boservice-impl/src/main/java/com/eqtechnologic/my/bo/api/apiimpl/bean/ExportDatasetSettings.java' indexed with language 'java'
14:29:38.323 DEBUG: 'Source/CommonModules/boservice/boservice-impl/src/main/java/com/eqtechnologic/my/bo/api/apiimpl/bean/ExportToTextSettings.java' indexed with language 'java'
14:29:38.323 DEBUG: 'Source/CommonModules/boservice/boservice-impl/src/main/java/com/eqtechnologic/my/bo/api/apiimpl/bean/EmailSettings.java' indexed with language 'java'
14:29:38.323 DEBUG: 'Source/CommonModules/boservice/boservice-impl/src/main/java/com/eqtechnologic/my/bo/api/apiimpl/bean/ExportToExcelSettings.java' indexed with language 'java'
14:29:38.323 DEBUG: 'Source/CommonModules/boservice/boservice-impl/src/main/java/com/eqtechnologic/my/bo/api/apiimpl/bean/ExportPowerPointExportOptions.java' indexed with language 'java'
14:29:38.323 DEBUG: 'Source/CommonModules/boservice/boservice-impl/src/main/java/com/eqtechnologic/my/bo/api/apiimpl/bean/EmbeddedExportSettings.java' indexed with language 'java'
14:29:38.324 DEBUG: 'Source/CommonModules/boservice/boservice-impl/src/main/java/com/eqtechnologic/my/bo/api/apiimpl/WidgetModelWrapperFactory.java' indexed with language 'java'
14:29:38.324 DEBUG: 'Source/CommonModules/boservice/boservice-impl/src/main/java/com/eqtechnologic/my/bo/api/apiimpl/boServiceController.java' indexed with language 'java'
14:29:38.324 INFO: Indexing files of module 'boservice'
14:29:38.324 INFO:   Base dir: /home/oracle/jenkins/workspace/RedmineAndReviewboardProject/SVNCheckout@8/branch_dev/Source/CommonModules/boservice
14:29:38.324 DEBUG:   Source paths: .
14:29:38.385 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:29:38.385 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
14:29:38.385 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:29:38.385 INFO: Total time: 2.442s
14:29:38.431 INFO: Final Memory: 9M/442M
14:29:38.431 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: i recommend to run the sonarscanner in debug mode, and provide this log. The sensors used, etc. can provide a lot of insights. Furhtermore it would be also good to post your sonar-project.properties if there is one. It might be just minor configuration detail within that file.

Comment: Thanks Simon for reply! I updated question with sonar-project.properties and debug log.

Comment: so i write this as a comment, as i am not 100% sure and do not have the time to verify this, and my migration from 6 to 7 is quiet a long time ago. else i would suggest the sonar community where you most likely will get help. I do think that the problem lies in your multiple module configuration, which also contains each other. so a file will get analyzed twice once in the Source module and once in the backoffice module. But i can not guarantee that this is the real answer, that would be my first tackle point.